# CQ-Dialog page properties can not be stored from site admin but works from sidekick

Tags: aem

The purpose of the following function is to allow the user to save the edited `page properties in the CQ-Dialog` even though if they invalid by clicking on the button `save anyway`:

```
 PageProperties.showMsg = function(dialog, config, errorMessage) {
    CQ.Ext.MessageBox.buttonText.ok = "save anyway";
    CQ.Ext.Msg.show({
        title : "Completeness check failed",
        msg : errorMessage,
        buttons: CQ.Ext.Msg.OKCANCEL,
        fn : function(buttons) {
            if(buttons == "ok") {

                dialog.form.items.each(function(field) {
                    // clear fields with emptyText so emptyText is not submitted
                    if (field.emptyText && field.el && field.el.dom && field.el.dom.value == field.emptyText) {
                        field.setRawValue("");
                    }
                });
                var action = new CQ.form.SlingSubmitAction(dialog.form, config);
                dialog.form.isValid = function() {
                    return true;
                };
                dialog.form.doAction(action);
                dialog[dialog.closeAction]();
                CQ.Util.reload();
            }
        }
    }); 
};
```

This functions works fine from the `sidekick`. When I click on `save anyway` all current values of the page properites are stored regardless if they are valid or not. This does not work from the `site admin`. when I call the `page properties` of the same page from the `site admin` and try to save the page properties with invalid values by clicking on `save anyway`, this does not works (old values are stored and nothing changes).

I hope somebody can help. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. the problem was the function `CQ.Util.reload()`. It prevent storing the values